# flutter local notification default sound doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I implement the flutter local notification and it successfully send notification but with no sound . I make playSound : true ,it should play the default sound but it is not working . I uninstall and reinstall the app and still not working . Please give me a solution .

Code :

```
_testNotification() async {
        const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
            AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
               playSound: true,
                showWhen: false);
        const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
            NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
            payload: 'item x');
      }
```

Comment: do you have a solution for this problem ? @Sajid ikram

Comment: Test it on real device it will work.

Comment: i tested it on Redmi Xiomi but not working yet...the default sound and the custom  @Sajid ikram

Comment: It work for me on samsung but when I release my app to the play store one Xiomi user complain the same notification problem, still it can't find any solution of this problem for some mobiles.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem while running the app on my Redmi note pro 7

Comment: No bro, I did not find any solution.  If u find any please let me know.